# One butt muscle is getting bigger

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, bodyweight-exercises, muscle-gain, muscle-imbalance

I'm 20 yrs old and been working out, doing leg and butt workouts. I'm seeing great results on my left buttcheek, it's getting bigger, with more muscle and its firm. on the other hand, my right buttcheek seems to be growing very slow, its growing, but im seeing very slow results. I've been doing squats and lunges, also I've been researching and some people said to do single butt workouts on my weaker (right) buttcheek, but another person said not to do single butt workouts because i'll only burn the fat off and my left (muscled) buttcheek will stay bigger with the muscle I've gained and fat I have on it. I can't seem to find answers because most (or all) questions and answered questions I find, only discuss about imbalanced fat and no one seems to have this problem, I, on the other hand am having imbalanced muscle trouble. What should I do? just leave it? A friend suggested I try burn the fat off my left (muscled) butt, but I'm scared the muscle will only get bigger. any answers?

Answer (score 2):

**Bret Contreras, aka "The Glute Guy"** who is known as the world's glute training expert (he literally wrote his [PhD thesis on glute exercise activation](https://bretcontreras.com/wp-content/uploads/A-Comparison-of-Gluteus-Maximus-Biceps-Femoris-and-Vastus-Lateralis-Electromyographic-Activity-in-the-Back-Squat-and-Barbell-Hip-Thrust-Exercises-2.pdf)) talks about how glute imbalances are very common – much more common than you’d imagine, in his [article about how to fix glute imbalances](https://bretcontreras.com/how-to-fix-glute-imbalances/).

[You cannot spot target fat](http://www.yalescientific.org/2011/04/targeted-fat-loss-myth-or-reality/), so whoever told you that you will burn the fat off of one side and not the other is incorrect (if I am understanding you correctly).

You can, however, spot target muscle. So your research has been correct. Bret says the first thing you want to do in order to try to fix a gluteal imbalance is perform a bunch of extra work for the weaker glute. Here is another one of his [articles explaining the 2-1 method for glute imbalances](https://bretcontreras.com/2-1-method-fixing-glute-imbalances/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much... My butt was perfectly even before I started working out but I will look into these. And when I do stretches before a workout I've noticed my weaker leg or buttcheek couldnt do some of the stretches my strong left leg could do. Therefore, I had a feeling it had to do with one leg being longer than the other, of something within my bone structure. Thank you once again!